# Get umbraco property with inline C#

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm trying to show content in my masterpage depending on a true/false property on my document type. I'm using inline C# and i got this far:

```
<% if (umbraco.library.IsLoggedOn() && umbraco.library.GetXmlNodeById("0").GetProperty("protectContent").Value.ToString() == "1") {%> 
<h1>Logged on and showing protected content</h1>
<%}%>
```

This is the error message i get:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperty' and no extension method 'GetProperty' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Final solution:
Based on Digbyswifts solution i got it working with this snippet:

```
<%if (umbraco.NodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent().GetProperty("protectContent").Value.ToString().Equals("1")) {%> 
    <pre>Showing protected content</pre>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the node ID, you could just use

```
new Node(id).GetProperty("protectContent").Value.ToString() == "1"
```

However, if you are on the page you wish to query, you can just use:

```
Node.GetCurrent().GetProperty("protectContent").Value.ToString() == "1"
```

If I'm using masterpages, I like to have a `CurrentNode` accessor in my codebehind .cs file that returns `Node.GetCurrent()` but has a backing field so it is not requested each time I call it, e.g.

```
public partial class BaseMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public Node CurrentNode { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentNode = Node.GetCurrent();
    }
}
```